# PowerPoint 2010 has large spaces in-between characters

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

My PowerPoint 2010 suddenly has large spaces in-between characters and it seems like some of the styles also had this same issue. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the result of one (or both) of two things:

1) No printer driver installed and set as default (or at least no *adequate* printer driver as default).  If you have no other printer drivers handy, make the Microsoft XPS Document Writer the default printer.

2) The presentation calls for a font that isn't installed. Check to see what font the text boxes "think" they are, then go to Control Panel | Fonts to verify that the font really is installed in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by choosing paragraphs with this problem in every slide and align it left (ctrl + L).

[image: Align Left]